# Append query failing due to validation errors when no validation rules exist (Access)

Tags: validation, ms-access, append, ms-access-2013

I am trying to append data from one table to another in Access 2013.  The destination table, `[ActionItems]`, has no records yet.

The source table, `[Students]`, has the necessary columns: `[AutoID]` (Autonumber), `[Action Status]` (Short text), `[Action Status Last Updated]` (Date/time), `[Action Status Description]` (Short text).

I have set the destination table to match the data types and fields (though the field names are slightly different, I have joined them appropriately in the append query).  The `[AutoID]` field in the destination table is set to Number, Long Integer, as I've read suggested elsewhere.

If I view the append query in datasheet view, I see 731 records, just as I should.  But when I try to run the query, I get the following error:

> "Microsoft Access can't append all the records... set 0 field(s) to
>   Null due to a type conversion failure... 0... key violations... 0...
>   lock violations, and **731 record(s) due to validation rule
>   violations**."

There are **NO** validation rules in the destination table!  Both text fields allow for zero length, and the `[AutoID]` field has no default value.  I don't understand what I could be missing.

Here is my SQL (I realize my column names are rather wordy):

```sql
INSERT INTO [ActionItems] ( AutoID, [Action Status], [Action Status Last Updated], [Action Status Description] )
SELECT [Students].[AutoID (Do not use)], [Students].Status, [Students].[Status Last Updated], [Students].[Status Description]
FROM [Students];
```

If it helps, here is a link to a stripped-down version of the database: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BysgnYaEVPnJemNnOUc3ZmFsWXM/view?usp=sharing

I have removed all other tables and any identifiable information.  The only other major difference is that the primary key in the `[Students]` table was changed from a composite key (`[First Name]`, `[Last Name]`, and `[Email]`) to a single primary key (`[AutoID (Do not use)]`).  I made no changes at all to the `[ActionItems]` table.  Even with these changes, the error still occurs exactly as previously described.

Comment: Post your sql from your query. That might help figure it out.

Comment: Ah, of course... I just added it!

Comment: Validation rules exist not only on field level, but also on table level. In table design, open the property sheet and check the `ValidationRule` property of the table.

Comment: @Violet Sorry, without being able to see your table design, I can't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: Andre, that's a good point... I had forgotten that was even possible.  Unfortunately those properties were blank.  Based on what randyh22 said, I have updated my question with a link to a stripped-down version of the database itself.  I hope that may prove helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination table, `ActionItems`, includes a field named `Action Status Last Updated By`.  That field's *Required* property is set to *Yes*, and its *Default Value* property is blank.  That means any time you add a new row to that table, you **must** supply a value for `Action Status Last Updated By`.

Notice your `INSERT` statement does not supply anything for `Action Status Last Updated By`.  Therefore that `INSERT` does not add any rows.

In my copy of your database, I changed the field's *Required* property to *No*. After that change, executing your `INSERT` query added 731 rows to `ActionItems` ... one for every row in `Students`.

If you prefer a different solution, you could leave *Required* set to *True* and either put something in the field's *Default Value* property or alter the `INSERT` to supply a value for that field.

Comment: HansUp, you save the day again!  Wow, I don't know how I missed that.  I will probably put in a default value, something like "system" or "unknown" (moving forward a macro will be updating the field based on the current user's username, so it's not too dire).  Thank you so much!

Comment: What is the best way to pinpoint the error. e.g. what colum generating error, what data value is generating error etc. to solve the append error by trial-and-fix-and-procced method?

Comment: I examine the Required and Default Value properties for each of the fields in the destination table which are not accounted for in the `INSERT` statement.  If any of those fields has Required = Yes but no Default Value defined, the `INSERT` must supply a value in order to avoid an error.